# Table Cell overlapped on Delete button when delete table cell in ios7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Table cell background views are overlapping on the delete button when i want to delete a table cell (see below screenshot). How can i rectify this issue. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can't see the screenshot?

Comment: need more information

Answer (score 0):

try using the accessoryView and editingAccessoryView properties of your UITableViewCell, instead of adding the view yourself.

If you want the same indicator displayed in both editing and none-editing mode, try setting both view properties to point at the same view in your uiTableViewCell like:

```
self.accessoryView = self.imgPushEnabled;
self.editingAccessoryView = self.imgPushEnabled;
```

There seems to be a glitch in the table editing animation in IOS7, giving an overlap of the delete button and the accessoryView when switching back to non-editing state. This seems to happen when the accesoryView is specified and the editingAccessoryView is nil.

A workaround for this glitch, seems to be specifying an invisible editingAccessoryView like:

```
self.editingAccessoryView =[[UIView alloc] init];
self.editingAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate your cell's content view in your layout subviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIView *view = [self.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 0.2f;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [view.layer addAnimation: animation forKey:@"deletingFade"];
}
```

Hope it helps!